# I need the contents of an iframe to expand like an animation and fill up the entire screen and shrink to it original size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need the contents of an iframe which has height of 100px(displays only part of iframe) to expand like an animation on read more button click,and fill up the entire screen(expands in all directions), and on clicking close button positioned on top of it, it needs to animate and shrink to it original size.

I found a fiddle that dooes something similar
http://jsfiddle.net/FP2DZ/.

But my issue is that my div cannot be absolutely positioned as I have contents underneath that and that gets affected if I make this one absolutely positioned. 
Absolutely positioning rest of the contents also does not seem to me like a good solution

Code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var isFullscreen = false;

        function fullscreen(){

        //var  d = document.getElementById('controls').style;
        var d = {};
        var speed = 900;
        if(!isFullscreen){ // MAXIMIZATION

        /*comment to have smooth transition from centre but loose covering the header*/
        //document.getElementById('controls').style.position= "absolute";

        d.width = "100%";
        d.height="100%";                    
        //d.left="0%";
        d.top="0px";
        //d.margin="0 0 0 0";
        $("#header").animate({ 
        height: 0
        }, speed);
        $("#controls2").animate(d,speed);

        isFullscreen = true;
        }else{ // MINIMIZATION

        d.width="300px";
        d.height="100px";
        d.margin="0 auto";
        d.position="relative";
        //d.top="+=30px";

        /* comment to have smooth minimze transition but not be placed below header */
        // document.getElementById('controls').style.position= "relative";

        $("#header").animate({ 
        height: 30
        }, speed);
        $("#controls2").animate(d,speed);
        isFullscreen = false;
        }

        }

    </script> 
    <style> 
        * { margin: 0 }

        #controls {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        left: 50%;
        z-index:5;
        } 
        #controls2 {
        overflow:visible;
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative; 
        left: -50%; 
        background-color: green;
        z-index:10;
        } 

    </style> 

</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="header" align=center> Header (To be covered on Fullscreen) </h1>
    <div id='controls' style="" align="center">

        <div id='controls2'>
            <input type='button' value='fullscreen' onclick='fullscreen();' /><br>
            I am some centered shrink-to-fit content! <br />
            tum te tum
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to utilize the .animate({}) method in Jquery.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cm6v7bca/2/

```
$("#clickhere").on("click", function () {
$("#myframe").animate({
    width: "200px",
    height: "200px"
}, 1000);
});
```

.animate({}) allows you to change the css properties and then smoothly animates the changes onto the element. There are several different parameters you can pass. In the fiddle you'll see that I passed "1000" - that's the duration for the animation to complete in ms.

You can read more about the parameters and the method here: https://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score -1):

That really helps. But then the iframe needs to cover rest of the contents in the page and overlay them, Thats seems possible only if iframe is absolutely positioned. But there is so much dynamic content in the page, I do not want to absolute position the iframe.

http://jsfiddle.net/CvhkM/2833/

this is like what I want just that am not able to absolute position.

JS:

```
$(this).stop().animate({
    left: parseInt(this.style.left)-100,
    top: parseInt(this.style.top)-100,
    width: parseInt(this.style.width)+200,
     height: parseInt(this.style.height)+200
}, 300);
```